# Multi Bullet Shot Xna

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vector, xna

I previously posted on this and showed my code for getting an explosion of bullets
going in a number of directions all at one time.

I was just wondering if someone could give me a clean example that I can go off of.

My idea was to have my left click make the player throw a grenade and when it collides with an enemy it explodes and bullets come out of every direction.

sorry for the double post,
thanks.

Comment: No one is going to give you a full sample to work off. Posting what you have and asking for improvements on the other hand is more acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(whatever the collision code is for xna again)
{
bullets.add(new bullet(startpos, direction))
}
```

if you expand that... bullets is whatever your using to manage your bullets, bullet is your newly created particle with a start position being where your collision took place, the direction will be a direction that your bullet should travel in (1 for north,ne,east,se,south,sw, west, nw) or whatever yo uwant